# Prometheus tumbling window aggrgeates

Tags: prometheus, promql

I would like to have aggregates from specific time ranges. E.g. hourly, daily, but hourly to be from e.g. 09:00-10:00 (tumbling window), not 1h ago (hopping window).

That would be possible if we could substract counters offsetted by variable time, e.g.:

`x_count offset (minutes()m) - x_count offset ((minutes()+60)m)` but offset does not seem to evaluate functions.

Suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: does the downvote mean this is not feasible in prometheus?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`timestamp()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#timestamp) function in combination with [`hour()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#hour) and [`day_of_month()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#day_of_month) to filter for samples falling within a given hour/day; or in combination with [`time()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#time) to filter for samples falling within the current hour/day.

Here's a brain teaser to get you started:

```
up{job="prometheus"} + ignoring(year, month, day_of_month) group_right
  count_values without() ("year", year(timestamp(
    count_values without() ("month", month(timestamp(
      count_values without() ("day_of_month", day_of_month(
        timestamp(up{job="prometheus"}
      )))
    )))
  ))) * 0
```

This will create separate metrics, for every `year`, `month` and `day_of_month` label combination. You can then `avg_over_time` (or anything `_over_time`) over those metrics; or aggregate them by year, month, day of month. Something like `rate()` would be trickier, as you would likely need to compute `rate()` over short ranges (e.g. 1 minute) and then average it out over time, so you'd need recording rules or [subqueries](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#subquery) for that.

Comment: oh my, I will try it